# Frontpage module redirecting to /user/uid not correct url on login

Tags: 7

The [frontpage module](https://www.drupal.org/project/front) redirects to `/user/uid` on login, not the specified redirect URL. All config looks correct. I have all redirects set to `node/1` which is where I want it to redirect.

[image]

Comment: Ok... is there any other config? Did you try this as user 1 or a lower level role?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a rule for this. when user logged in site then it will redirect on node/1 site.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It was due to a conflict of other modules. The ajax_register/bootstrap_login_modal modules were disrupting normal redirect flow with their config since AJAX redirects in forms are handled differently.

Comment: Please improve this answer to better explain which modules, and what the actual conflict was. Then afterwards mark this answer as "accepted" (so that it is no longer considered as unanswered).